Waring on Report Builder 2024
Does anyone gets this warrning when try to open Report Builder .rdl (new version from 2024)?
"This report contains expressions or code blocks that could modify or delete your local files. Only run reports from a trusted source."
Can someone help understand waht it means?

It probably means there is some custom VB code in the report. It won't analyse the code so it's there as a warning only. Only you can really verify if it safe by looking at the code itself.

This is just a "heads-up" that you should only run reports from trusted sources.  This is similar to macros in Excel.
